# Getting standard output from a Python Gnome Applet

Tags: python, applet, gnome

I'm currently writing a Gnome Panel Applet in Python. Everything is working fine as long as I don't try to actually add it to the panel (running it in a window works).

When trying to add it to a panel it crashes and I have no idea why, because I can't see the error trace.

Is there a simple way to log the output of a Gnome Applet to a file so I can find the problem?

Comment: Are you talking of GNOME 2.x applets?

Comment: Do you have a code with a minimal test case?

Answer (score 2):

stdout and stderr of applications started via X or one of its children are written to `~/.xsession-errors` if not redirected.

Comment: What would be a way to redirect all output to a file then?

Comment: Open a terminal, run `$ tail -f .xsession-errors` and the launch add your applet.  At the end of the day, you want to get the errors in order to fix your applet, no matter where they come from.